# Dataframes Join in Scala with multiple columns is not same with few columns might be null

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, join

I have 2 dataframes as below.

Goal is to find a new row from df2 where the same column values are not exist in dataframe 1.

I have tried to join the two dataframes with id as join condition and checked other column values are not equal as below.

But it does not work.

Could someone please assist?

df1: This dataframe is like a master table

```
id   amt    city    date

abc  100    City1   9/26/2018
abc  100    City1   9/25/2018
def  200    City2   9/26/2018
ghi  300    City3   9/26/2018
```

df2: Dataframe 2 which is new dataset comes everyday.

```
id   amt      city    date

abc  100      City1   9/27/2018
def  null     City2   9/26/2018
ghi  300      City3   9/26/2018
```

Result: Come up with a result dataframe as below:

```
id   amt    city    date
abc  100    City1   9/27/2018
def  null   City2   9/26/2018
```

Code I tried:

```
val writeDF = df1.join(df2, df1.col("id") === df2.col("id")).
    where(df1.col("amt") =!= df2.col("amt")).where(df1.col("city") =!= 
    df2.col("city")).where(df1.col("date") =!= df2.col("date")).select($"df2.*")
```

Answer (score 0):

DataFrame method `df1.except(df2)` will return all of the rows in `df1` that are not present in `df2`.

Source: [Spark 2.2.0 Docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@except(other:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T])

Answer (score 0):

Except method can be used as mentioned in scala [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.2/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset).

```scala
dataFrame1.except(dataFrame2)
```

will return another dataframe containing rows of dataFrame1 but not dataFrame2

Answer (score 0):

you need to use except method to achieve this.

```
df2.except(df1).show
```

[image]